# About javascript validation in liferay webform

Tags: javascript, validation, webforms, liferay, liferay-6

I use liferay 6.1 ga1. In my webform I want to validate input email so I tried:

```
if(typeof currentFieldValue.match('^([0-9a-zA-Z]([-\.\w]*[0-9a-zA-Z])*@([0-9a-zA-Z][-\w]*[0-9a-zA-Z]\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,9})')[0] !== 'undefined'){return true;}else{return false};
```

It does not work, but it not my trouble, it return javascript error and I can not change my javascript validate code-> big trouble here
To fix javascript validate code, 
I must to:

```
- Stop server
- Change validation.script.enabled to false 
- Start server
- Change javascript validate code
- Stop server
- Change validation.script.enabled to true
- Start server
- Check and Hope my code will work ( but it usually will not )
```

:((
Is there any faster and better way, please show me

Comment: I had tried change my code stored in database ( portletpreferences) but it not affected

Answer (score 0):

Two Things here.

1. Please post your javascript error and try to find out why it is coming?
2. If it is too much of a troublesome process, you can simply delete the portlet and add a new one again and try fixing it.

All the webform settings and configurations are stored as portlet preferences. Portlet preferences are temporarily stored in database, if you delete the portlet from the page, preferences will removed along with it.

Comment: yeah, I had thought so, but a little more trouble, actually i had tried to delete(remove) that webform portlet from my page, but when i refresh(f5) it still there...

Comment: This means that, the portlet is not getting deleted. Can you please try it on a fresh new page? If it works, delete the current page.. not a good way to solve but effective.